# Dynamically set image url from database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to check if the code **DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Product.ImageName")** is empty then set src=""

```
 <asp:Image ID="ImgProd" src='<%# string.Format("~/ProductImages/{0}{1}",DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Product.ImageName"),".jpg")%>' runat="server" Width="100px" Height="100px" />
```

how to do this can anybody help me !

Comment: is this in a repeater?

Answer (score 0):

I image your imagecontrol is in a Repeater or a similar databound control:

ascx/aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myrepeater" OnItemDataBound="MyrepeaterItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        ...
        <asp:Image ID="ImgProd" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="100px" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

codebehind:

```
protected void MyrepeaterItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var myObject = (MyDataSourceObject)e.Item.DataItem;
        var image = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("ImgProd");
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myObject.Product.ImageName))
        {
            image.ImageUrl=string.Format("~/ProductImages/{0}.jpg", myObject.Product.ImageName );           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All I got this one :)

```
<asp:Image ID="ImgProd" src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Product.ImageName")!=""?string.Format("../../ProductImages/{0}{1}",DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Product.ImageName"),".jpg"):""%>' runat="server" Width="100px" Height="100px" />
```